# Convert date Excel from string to date

Tags: excel, date, type-conversion, dataset

I am trying to convert my date format. I am using Italian language as default. My date is "February 28, 2014" and I want Excel to understand that it is a date and to write it as "2014-02-28". Using just "change format tab" doesn't work. What should I do? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the format in excel ,Click `Home` Tab in the Ribbon-> In `number` Group->Choose `more number format` (an arrow at right bottom in the group in my case)-> `Date`->change the 'type' as `YYYY-MM-DD"` at that should work :)
I took screenshots, my excel in french but I hope it helps!
[image: number goupe in the ribbon]
[image: date option]

Comment: Merci for your answer, but unfortunately this is how I usually do it and today's not working.